# Getting PSOD while installing Esxi 7.0 on Virtual Box

Tags: vmware, vsphere, esxi

I was trying to install Esxi 7.0 on virtual box but I'm getting the following error.

[PSOD error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/1DQPo.png)

I tried with Esxi 6.5 but was getting similar kind of error.

VM Config: 4Cpus, 4GB RAM,40GB HDD

My Machine Specs: i7 8th Gen 8 cores, 32 RAM

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The ESXi installer is itself ESXi and you're in a chicken and egg situation where the installer is crashing and you have no core dump file or partition configured.  You can tell this from the bottom 3 lines:

- No place on disk to dump data.
- No file configured to dump data.
- No port for remote debugger.  "Escape" for local debugger.

If you're really brave press the "Escape" key and you can get to the kernel text logs which can frequently tell you a lot about the cause of the crash.  But reading the logs at the PSOD prompt is a pain and something I try to avoid by always having a place to dump the core file (the "data" referred to above).

I'd suggest that you either install ESXi to a USB flash drive on bare hardware (see https://www.nakivo.com/blog/run-esxi-from-usb-flash-drive-guide/) or grab an ESXi dd-image and put that on either a physical or virtual USB flash drive (https://www.virten.net/2014/12/clone-esxi-installations-on-sd-cards-or-usb-flash-drives/).  You can then pass the USB image through to your virtual environment.  By doing it this way you will already have created a core dump partition so that if ESXi crashes you can get a core dump.  The ESXi kernel logs, which are text files, are part of the core dump and https://communities.vmware.com/t5/ESXi-Discussions/Kernel-Dump-Analysis-Tool/td-p/1429887 has some guidance on extracting them from the dump.

Lastly, if you simply must do everything in a virtual environment you could try creating a core dump partition on a second disk (type 0xFC and size 2+GB) and maybe if you're lucky the installer will pick it up.  If you can get to a command prompt before the PSOD then you can use esxcli to create, configure and make active a core dump partition but pay ignore size recommendations under 2 GB.  Nothing is as frustrating as a truncated core dump.  See https://kb.vmware.com/s/article/2004299 for more info.

Comment: I took took the cowards way out by not solving the actual problem and tried the installation on VMware WorkStation and it worked perfectly. Thanks for the ans though, will try it when I get some time.